# Не могу получить html

Tags: jquery

Есть форма с элементами внутри, типа:

```
<span class="field">
     <label class="k_f_desc editor mce-content-body" id="mce_23" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;">Тест</label><input type="hidden" name="mce_23">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
</span>
и т.д...
```

Есть перебор элементов через each, вот внутренний код:

```
$('form').find('input[type=text]:first').parents(".field").outerHTML();
```

Задача: получить элемент вместе с родителем, то есть с `<span class="field">...</span>`
Выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).parents(...).outerHTML is not a function
at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (script.js:594)
```

Раньше работало, сейчас не знаю даже почему перестало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как раньше работало то? `outerHtml` - функция `javascript`'a. Вам нужно как то так

```js
console.log($(document).find('input[type=text]:first').parents(".field")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="field">
     <label class="k_f_desc editor mce-content-body" id="mce_23" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;">Тест</label><input type="hidden" name="mce_23">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
</span>
```

Либо у вас гдето была определена функция именно `outerHTML()` и гдето затерлась :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! У меня отсутствовал номер объекта [0]. Полдня просидел)

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = $('form')
        .find('input[type=text]:first')
        .parents(".field")
        .clone()
        .wrap('<p>')
        .parent()
        .html();
console.log(s);
```